# Python: How to join lines following a string

Tags: python, text-files

I would like to know how would I use python to join certain lines in a large text file, that come after a certain string. For example my file is:

```
ID 1
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
ID 2
ABCDE
FGHIJ
ID 3
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
PQRST
```

And I would like to join the lines following each “ID”, but the number of lines after each varies. So I’d like my file to be

```
ID 1
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
ID 2
ABCDEFGHIJ
ID 3
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
```

The actual file has thousands of “ID” lines, so I’d like to find out how to identify the pattern to use.

I have not tried anything yet. I’m not sure where to start.

Comment: Loop through the file. If the current line and previous line don't begin with `ID`, append the current line to the previous line.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer without writing the code for you.

Comment: Thank you, I get what you are referring to, I just do not know any code to do that.

Comment: If you don't have a specific question to ask, how are we supposed to answer?

Comment: My specific question is what code would I use to do this. I am a beginner so I’m not sure how else to form this question.

Comment: You are currently the only one having an issue with this while others are being helpful, I have seen many similar posts from other beginners. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

To read the input file,

```
results = []
current = []
ids = []

with open("test.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[:2] == 'ID':
            ids.append(line)
            results.append(''.join(current) + '\n')
            current = []
        else:
            current.append(line.strip())
results.append(''.join(current))
```

To write the result to an output file,

```
with open("output.txt",'w') as f:
    for id_str,res in zip(ids,results[1:]):
        f.write(id_str)
        f.write(res)
```

Comment: This will miss outputting the last section, and lose the actual IDs from the input.

Comment: @blhsing Fair point on both counts; I've changed my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you! I understand what most of this is doing except for the “‘’ join(current) + ‘\n’”, could someone explain exactly what that line is doing?

Comment: @Holly234 current is the list of lines (with the newline characters at the end stripped) that come after the most recent ID line. When a new ID line is encountered, these lines are joined together into a long string (which is what ''.join does), a newline character is added to the end of that string, and that resulting string is added to the list "results" of lines that will be written into the output (after the corresponding IDs).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` with a negative lookahead pattern to substitute lines that do not start with `'ID '` and are not followed by `'ID '` with the same line but without a trailing newline character:

```
import re

with open('input.txt') as file:
    print(re.sub(r'^(?!ID )(.*)\n(?!ID )', r'\1', file.read(), flags=re.M))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ImmaterialPepperyForms

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with a key function that checks whether if a line starts with `ID` , and then join the groups of lines according to this key:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('input.txt') as file:
    print(
        '\n'.join(
            lines[0] if k else ''.join(lines)
            for k, [*lines] in groupby(
                map(str.rstrip, file),
                lambda line: line.startswith('ID ')
            )
        )
    )
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/MediumHonoredVendor

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the file in-place by opening the file twice, once for reading and another for writing. Skip outputting the trailing newline character if a line does not start with `'ID '`. If a line does start with `'ID '`, output a newline character for the previous line if it isn't the first line. Truncate the file at the end:

```
with open('file.txt') as file, open('file.txt', 'r+') as output:
    for line in file:
        if not line.startswith('ID '):
            line = line.rstrip()
        elif output.tell():
            output.write('\n')
        output.write(line)
    output.write('\n')
    output.truncate()
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/CapitalAngryKeygen

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way would be to use the '+' string operator to keep concatenating lines till a new line with an 'ID' string is found:

```
data = f.readlines()
out = []
curr_cat_line = ''

for line in data:
   if line.find('ID')!=-1:
       out.append(line)
       if curr_cat_line !='': out.append(curr_cat_line)
       curr_cat_line = ''
   curr_cat_line = curr_cat_line + line
```

Comment: `ID` is only special at the beginning, so use `line.startswith('ID ')`

Comment: This will miss outputting the last section.